# Poor sync between Windows 10 and Google Calendar

Tags: windows, windows-10, android, calendar, google-calendar

I added the Google account into my Windows 10 cal app and everything's going mostly smoothly, except not.

For instance, I'd add two entries for the same day in the Windows 10 cal. I obviously expect to see those two entries in Google. Yet I only see one, the first one I added. No amount of "Refresh" makes it appear.

None of the event takes the whole day.

That's true for both the web version of the Google Cal and the Google smartphone version.

Any input?

Thanks.

E: Tried to enter two events into the Google Cal. Been half an hour, it's stil not in the Windows app, despite repeated "Refresh" presses.

Is there any third-party solution (not involving Outlook)? Because unless I profoundly misunderstand something about synching calendars, that's not the way it should work. I'm not a heavy calendar user but I'd like the same cal on my desktop and two of my Android devices being in-sync. Can we achieve it in those mid 2010's yet?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Google Calendar website, and have a short cut to it on your desktop or in your start menu.

You can install the Calendar web app that makes your calendar [available offline](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/1340696?hl=en), if that is important, by clicking the cog and selecting 'offline'

Comment: Not to sound like an asshole, but that mostly defeats the purpose of syncing calendars. What I'd love to have is identical events in both my Google Web Calendar, Google Android Calendar (those are the same basically) and Windows 10 calendar. I believe that's why them Windows people introduced the "Add a different account" feature into their calendar.

Answer (score -1):

had the exact same issue, and thought the same about the fact that it shouldnt be so complex to have a simple sync feature for calendars..... solved my issue by simply deactivating the "power saving mode" on my android....in a matter of 1second all my calendar synced. hope that helps you as well